# AlarmManager.RTC doesn't fire if the device is already awake

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

In a broadcast receiver for the USER_PRESENT broadcast, I'm setting an alarm like this:

```
Intent intentAfterAlarmFire = new Intent(context, ActivityAfterAlarmFire.class);
        PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1234567, intentAfterAlarmFire, 0);
AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC, myTime, alarmIntent);
```

It works as expected when the user unlocks the device after the alarm time has passed, however, it doesn't fire the alarm if the user woke the device up before alarm time and kept using it until alarm time is passed.

Shouldn't the AlarmManager.RTC (non-wake-up) fire anyway if the device is already awake?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
// It'll fire every 5 seconds, you can set your own time in place of cal.getTimeInMillis()    

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 5000, alarmIntent);
```